# Is it possible to set the caller id (CID/CLID) to Blocked in RingOut?

Tags: ruby, ringcentral, ringout, caller-id

I'm using the RingCentral RingOut API and I'm wondering if I can block the [caller ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID)?

The RingOut API only shows the `phoneNumber` property in the request format but RingCentral Online Account Portal can block the caller ID. Is there a way to do this?

API Reference: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefMakeRingOut

Request:

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/ring-out HTTP/1.1

{
    "from": {"phoneNumber": "+14155550100"},
    "callerId": {"phoneNumber": "+16505550100"},
    "to": {"phoneNumber": "+12125550100"},
    "playPrompt": true
}
```

I am using the Ruby SDK: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-ruby

```
rc.post('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/ring-out', payload: {
  from: {phoneNumber: "+14155550100"},
  callerId: {phoneNumber: "+16505550100"},
  to: {phoneNumber: "+12125550100"},
  playPrompt: true
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting the default RingOut Caller ID setting to `Blocked` for the extension and then making a RingOut call without an explicit `callerId` value so the default value will be used. You need to update the extension Caller ID setting separately from and before calling the the RingOut API. It's not currently possible set Caller ID to blocked in the RingOut API call itself.

To set the caller ID to `Blocked` in an account, use the Update Caller ID API:

API Reference: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefUpdateCallerId

Here are some examples using HTTP and the Ruby SDK:

**Update Caller ID API via HTTP**

```
PUT /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/caller-id
Authorization: Bearer <myAccessToken>

{
  "byFeature": [
    {
      "feature": "RingOut",
      "callerId": {
        "type": "Blocked"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update Caller ID API via Ruby SDK**

Using the [`ringcentral-ruby` SDK](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-ruby):

```
rc.put('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/caller-id', payload: {
  byFeature: [
    {
      feature: "RingOut",
      callerId: {
        type: "Blocked"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

**Update Caller ID via Web UI**

You can also update this setting using the Online Account Portal (https://service.ringcentral.com):

`Settings` > `Outbound Calls/Faxes` > `Caller ID` > `By Feature` > `RingOut from Web` > `Edit`

[image: RingCentral Update Caller ID]

**Making the RingOut Call**

When you make the RingOut call, simply omit the `callerId` property, and it will use the blocked value.